# Paste Values on Archive?

Tags: excel, vba, paste, archive

hoping you can help?

I am wanting to archive data when a cell turns to "closed"

I have found the following code but i need it to past VALUES into the Archive so that times dont keep updating?

```
Sub MoveRowsToNextTab()
'ExcelIsSimple-Subscribe at http://www.youtube.com/user/excelissimple?sub_confirmation=1
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim K As Long
    I = Worksheets("CSL").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    J = Worksheets("Archive").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If J = 1 Then
       If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Archive").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
    End If
    Set xRg = Worksheets("CSL").Range("C7:C" & I)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For K = 1 To xRg.Count
        If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Closed" Then
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Archive").Range("A" & J + 1)
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete
            If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Closed" Then
                K = K - 1
            End If
            J = J + 1
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Any ideas.... PS I have no idea what i am doing :)

tried adding

```
PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

after

```
xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy 
Destination:=Worksheets("Archive").Range("A" & J + 1)
```

but that did not work

Comment: Drop the destination clause from the copy statement, then read up on Range.PasteSpecial.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Sub MoveToArchive()
    Dim wsCSL As Worksheet
    Dim wsArchive As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowCSL As Long
    Dim lastRowArchive As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Set the worksheets
    Set wsCSL = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CSL")
    Set wsArchive = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Archive")
    
    ' Find the last row in CSL column C
    lastRowCSL = wsCSL.Cells(wsCSL.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through the rows in reverse order
    For i = lastRowCSL To 7 Step -1
        ' Check if the value in column C is "Closed"
        If CStr(wsCSL.Cells(i, "C").Value) = "Closed" Then
            ' Find the next empty row in Archive column A
            lastRowArchive = wsArchive.Cells(wsArchive.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            wsCSL.Rows(i).Cut Destination:=wsArchive.Cells(lastRowArchive + 1, "A")
            wsCSL.Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Archived complete."
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks very much.. seems to work well :) and a nice little message at the end :)

Comment: @ChrisFinner If the provided code successfully addresses your issue, it would be beneficial to designate it as the answer to assist others encountering the same problem